# cannot repair database in mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb

I accidentally deleted 2 data *(mydb.47, mydb.62)* files from my `/data/db` of my mongodb. I have rest of the files in place...

Now my mongodb won't start up..I tried repairing it using this command

```
sudo -u mongod  mongod  --dbpath /data/db-new --repair --repairpath /data/db
```

Repair finished with no errors. Mongo docs say

> You may also wish **to move the repaired files to the old database location** or update the dbPath to indicate the new location

I copied the files from `/data/db-new to /data/db` and started mongo server. But it is not starting...

Is there any way I could reclaim my data?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you cannot reclaim your data using MONGO. But you can go for some other third party tools that can help to recover data from your hard disk.

I hope this link will help [linux data recover on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)